# Convert DateObject into TimeObject

Tags: date-and-time

How to elegantly convert from `DateObject` to `TimeObject`?

The purpose is to extract time from the DateObject and manipulate only time components afterwards.

Comment: It seems that for the methods below to work, DateObject must contain the time. It is possible to have DateObject without the time, in which case error will be returned. A way around this is to call DateString[dateObject, {"Hour","Minute","Second", "Millisecond"}]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TimeObject` can take a `DateObject` so:

```
datetime = DateObject[]
time = TimeObject[datetime]
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the `FullForm` of a `DateObject` looks like this:

> `DateObject[List[2015,8,27],TimeObject[List[17,58,23.456762],Rule[TimeZone,-5.]],Rule[TimeZone,-5.]]`

we can use `Cases`:

```
now = DateObject[]
Cases[now, TimeObject[__]][[1]]
```

> [image]

Or even simpler:

```
now[[2]]
```

Comment: Not anymore: probably since v11.1, the full form is `DateObject[{2019, 5, 21, 12, 55, 24.6968067},  "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.]`.